# Workflow for automatically running sagetex in VSCode

Tags: sagetex, terminal-output, vscode

#### Notes

- This is my first post here; however, I have used the answers from here countless times.
- I am definitely a beginner with command line/terminal stuff.
- I would say I am pretty literate with LaTeX, in general.
- I just started using VSCode in the last couple weeks as my editor after switching from Texpad.

System: Mac
LaTeX IDE: VSCode with latex-workshop
Sage Version: 9.4

#### Intro

I recently started using sagetex to run sage code in my LaTeX documents. My use case is I do all my assignments in LaTeX for each engineering course. Sagetex lets me keep everything within LaTeX without needing to reformat/copy from MATLAB or something similar. I keep individual course folders stored in a central school folder like `/Users/home/Documents/school/class`. Everything works properly with sagetex: compile document with sage code, run `sage doc.sagetex.sage` in terminal, recompile document.

This process just seems bloated with having to set the directory to the folder enclosing the specific sagetex.sage file each time in terminal for a different assignment, as well as compiling twice for each time I wish to change answers in the document. I was experimenting with recipes in the settings.json, but it's definitely a bit over my head.

#### What I'm Trying to Do

I would like to create a VSCode recipe or terminal script to run in VSCode that does the following:

1. Compile LaTeX document
2. Set the directory in terminal to the enclosing folder of the sagetex.tex file (which is in the same directory as my tex file like the rest of the aux files)
3. Run `sage file.sagetex.sage`
4. Set the directory in terminal back to the home directory
5. Compile LaTeX document again

I guess the big question is if this is possible all within VSCode, or at all. If it is...how would I implement this. If I am missing something big or being a dummy in some way, I would love to hear! Thanks.

Comment: To do this you need to be a bash/VSCode expert, but those are mostly in other sites.